# How do i add a formula to a cell from a different cell?

Tags: excel-formula

The user enters any value in cell B3, this then makes the title **Property 1** appear in B2. I need it to also populate the C2 field with the same formula and so on.

I have a formula in cell B2, which is basically; If cell B3 has information in it, B2 will populate with **Property 1**. I then need to apply that same formula to the next cell in the sequence - C2, with Property 2, so on and so forth.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B3)),"Property "&COLUMN()-1,"")
```

The formula itself works very well, I have put it into all of the row 2 fields. The issue is that Excel prints pages with formulas. I've tried finding a way to stop printing the pages with only formulas, but there doesn't appear to be such a thing. As I don't know how many pages will be used, the formula needs to be clever enough to stop if the row 3 field is not populated.

Comment: It will help if you provide us with an example: what you want (just write the values without formulas) and what you get with your formulas. Please do this by editing the answer.

Comment: @virolino nice to see you here !

Comment: Nice to see you too :) I was not much active here since I am not  a web developer, and C / Excel / regex questions are not that many.

Comment: @virolino, sorry i don't follow, i thought i had explained it well. I want B2 to say Property 1 when B3 has any value entered, and then the same to happen to the next column with an increment of 1 (Property 2) and the next, until the end of the row. The formula cannot be already entered into the C though to XYZ columns beforehand as this would result in excel printing 500 odd pages.

Comment: That's not an excel formula problem, that is a printing settings problem. You might want to try to adjust those before printing, either by defining a printing area or selecting print selection. If it's too tedious, you could probably use VBA to clear all empty cells and print only the ones with values in it.

Comment: @Pomul, i had a look at the print area option, but as i will be sending this document to customers and the number of rows used will always change, its not an option. And sending Macro enabled Excel spreadsheets gets messy because of the security restriction Microsoft automatically imposes on them.

Comment: how does "The issue is that Excel prints pages with formulas. ".. and "add a formula to a cell from a different cell " relates? any sample data/file for others to reproduce the situation?

Comment: @Jimy Mason - The macro would be used to "clean" the document so that it can save/print it according to your specs. And if it came to it, you can have a macro that saves workbooks as .xls(x) files.

Comment: Hi @p._phidot_, They relate because i have a working formula, but i can't use it 
 because the formula would need to be in every cell in the row, which causes hundreds of blank pages to be printed. I will upload the document in question, but i'm new to Stack, where is the option to upload?

Comment: You may share the file using an online storage service like dropbox / google drive/ onedrive, then post the 'shared file' (view only/not editable) link here (edit and add in you question)..